# Creating a list of payments within certain months. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, between

I'm needing to return payments from June through the end of August 2005. I can't figure out how to return just those payments though. The code I have is just kind of my attempt at it.

```
/* Create a list of all the payments made in June, July and August of 2005, and, if they were for a rental, the title of that rental. */

SELECT CONCAT(payment_id,' ',amount) AS Payments
FROM payment
INNER JOIN rental
ON payment.rental_id = rental.rental_id
WHERE payment_date = 2005-06-01 - 2005-08-31;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code with appropriate using of `BETWEEN` operator

```
/* Create a list of all the payments made in June, July and August of 2005, and, if they were for a rental, the title of that rental. */

SELECT CONCAT(payment_id,' ',amount) AS Payments
FROM payment
INNER JOIN rental
ON payment.rental_id = rental.rental_id
WHERE payment_date BETWEEN '2005-06-01' AND '2005-08-31';
```